# How to change authors font size without changing font face

Tags: fontsize, templates, acm

I am using ACM PROC format and want to change the font size of emails in the author list. When I use `\small`, the font-face also changes. Is it possible to only change the font size?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}

\title{Title}

\author{Name$^{\dag}$, Name$^{\dag}$, Name$^{\dag\ddag}$...\\
\affaddr{$\dag$ University, Address}\\
\affaddr{$\ddag$ University, Address} \\
\affaddr{\small email, email,email}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Here is the link to the template: http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates#aL2

Comment: Can you post a link to the class? That's not part of a standard distribution. Note that if you are using a class for a journal or conference, you almost certainly ought not change the font attributes at all as they will want them as they have configured them.

Comment: @cfr I don't want to change the template. I just want to resize the font-size of emails, and I have seen other papers have done the same thing with the same template. Here is the link to the template files: http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates#aL2

Comment: I actually did it, by adding the following code to my latex file: `\newfont{\eaddfnts}{phvr8t at 9pt} \n \def\email#1{{{\eaddfnts{\par #1}}}}`

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution seems to be to just add the `\sffamily` switch to the field.

Chances are high though, that the journal editors will ust revert the changes.

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}

\title{Title}

\author{Name$^{\dag}$, Name$^{\dag}$, Name$^{\dag\ddag}$...\\
\affaddr{$\dag$ University, Address}\\
\affaddr{$\ddag$ University, Address} \\
\affaddr{\scriptsize\sffamily email, email,email}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image: emabTitle.]